# Querying data from different tables, Union

Tags: mysql

This is really confusing me.

I have many different tables for sales orders:

**Table 1 = tv_product** 
product_tv_id (Primary Key) = number for product 
code = Product Code
name = Description
bom = bill of materials product (1 or 0)
is_archived = old product not used any more (1 or 0)

**Table 2 = tv_sales_orders**
sales_order_id (Primary Key) = Order ID
total_discount = Discount applied to total order
status (12004 = cancelled)
completed_date

**Table 3 = tv_sales_orders_lines**
sales_order_id (Primary Key) (Foreign Key to tv_sales_orders)
product_tv_id (Primary Key) (Foreign Key to tv_product)
quantity
cost_price
line_total (Qty x cost price)

**Table 4 = tv_product_supplier**
tv_id (Primary Key) (Foreign Key to tv_product.product_tv_id)
supplier_id (Primary Key)

**Table 5 = tv_sales_orders_packing_lists** 
packing_list_id (Primary Key) 
sales_order_id (Foreign Key to tv_sales_orders.sales_order_id)
shipped_date

**Table 6 = tv_sales_orders_packing_list_lines**
packing_list_id (Primary Key)(Foreign Key to tv_sales_orders_packing_lists.packing_list_id)
product_id (Primary Key)(Foreign Key to tv_product.product_tv_id)
quantity_packed

There are many more lines in the tables and many more tables but I have just included the ones of intrest.

**Require:**

1. All the products listed under supplier (tv_product_supplier.supplier_id) = 3608989204038919213 (even if no sales of product between the date range) except for NOT tv_product.code="Ship" and
   products which have been archived (NOT is_archived = 1)
2. Total products sold, QTY and total price which were on orders not cancelled between date x and y listed by line item.

**Tried Code:**

**Attempt 1:**

```
  SELECT p.code as "Code", p.name as "Name", sum(sol.quantity) as "Qty", sum((sol.cost_price * sol.quantity)) as "Cost Total Excl", sum(sol.line_total) as "Sale Total incl"
    FROM tv_sales_orders as so
    Inner JOIN tv_sales_orders_lines as sol
    on so.sales_order_id = sol.sales_order_id
    Inner join tv_product as p
    on sol.product_tv_id = p.tv_id
    Inner join tv_product_supplier as ps
    on p.tv_id = ps.tv_id
    Where ps.supplier_id = "3608989204038919213" and NOT p.code = "SHIP" and completed_date BETWEEN '2021-08-20' AND '2021-08-26'
    group by p.code, p.name
    UNION
    SELECT p.code as "Code", p.name as "Name", 0 as "Qty", 0 as "Cost Total Excl", 0 as "Sale Total incl"
    FROM tv_product as p
    Inner join tv_product_supplier as ps
    on p.tv_id = ps.tv_id
    Where ps.supplier_id = "3608989204038919213" and NOT p.code = "SHIP" and NOT p.is_archived = 1
    group by p.code
    Order by "Code" ASC
```

**Problem:**

1. This works, but I end up with the union not joining the original query, the point of the second query is to get any items not on sales orders but an item provided by the supplier to be listed at the bottom, with 0 values, and the ones already listed from the original query i dont want them listed again. (1 unique line per code only)

[image]

**Really hoping someone can point me in the right direction for what the query should be please?
Thanks in advance**

Edit

Use:

```
SELECT p.code as "Code", p.name as "Name", sum(sol.quantity) as "Qty", sum((sol.cost_price * sol.quantity)) as "Cost Total Excl", sum(sol.line_total) as "Sale Total incl"
FROM tv_sales_orders as so
Inner JOIN tv_sales_orders_lines as sol
on so.sales_order_id = sol.sales_order_id
Inner join tv_product as p
on sol.product_tv_id = p.tv_id
Inner join tv_product_supplier as ps
on p.tv_id = ps.tv_id
Where ps.supplier_id = "1" and NOT p.code = "SHIP" and completed_date BETWEEN '2021-08-28' AND '2021-08-29'
group by p.code, p.name
UNION
SELECT p.code as "Code", p.name as "Name", 0 as "Qty", 0 as "Cost Total Excl", 0 as "Sale Total incl"
FROM tv_product as p
Inner join tv_product_supplier as ps
on p.tv_id = ps.tv_id
Where ps.supplier_id = "1"
group by p.code
Order by "Code" ASC
```

To get:

Only want 1 line per item

[image]

> SQL Dump:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `tv_product` (   `tv_id` varchar(28) NOT NULL,   `code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,   `name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
> ```
>
> `cost_price_ex_tax` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `sell_price_ex_tax`
> decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `weight` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,   `length`
> int(9) DEFAULT NULL,   `width` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,   `height` int(9)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `is_archived` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
> `local_update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `enable_inventory`
> tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,   `tv_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
> `short_description` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,   `is_bom` tinyint(1)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `new_product_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL )
> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> ### --
> -- Dumping data for table `tv_product`
>
> INSERT INTO `tv_product` (`tv_id`, `code`, `name`,
> `cost_price_ex_tax`, `sell_price_ex_tax`, `weight`, `length`, `width`,
> `height`, `is_archived`, `local_update_date`, `enable_inventory`,
> `tv_modified_date`, `short_description`, `is_bom`, `new_product_date`)
> VALUES ('1', 'gds1', 'gds1 name', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('2', 'gds2', 'gds2', NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL), ('3', 'gds3', 'gds3', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('4', 'gds4', 'gds4', NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
> ('5', 'gds5', 'gds5', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
>
> ---
>
> ### --
> -- Table structure for table `tv_product_supplier`
>
> CREATE TABLE `tv_product_supplier` (   `tv_id` varchar(28) NOT NULL,
> `supplier_id` varchar(28) NOT NULL,   `product_supplier_id`
> varchar(28) NOT NULL,   `supplier_product_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT
> NULL,   `supplier_price` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `is_price_incl`
> tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,   `box_qty` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
> `preferred_supplier` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,   `local_update_date`
> datetime DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> ### --
> -- Dumping data for table `tv_product_supplier`
>
> INSERT INTO `tv_product_supplier` (`tv_id`, `supplier_id`,
> `product_supplier_id`, `supplier_product_code`, `supplier_price`,
> `is_price_incl`, `box_qty`, `preferred_supplier`, `local_update_date`)
> VALUES ('1', '1', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('2', '1',
> '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('3', '1', '1', NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('4', '1', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL), ('5', '1', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
>
> ---
>
> ### --
> -- Table structure for table `tv_sales_orders`
>
> CREATE TABLE `tv_sales_orders` (   `sales_order_id` varchar(28) NOT
> NULL,   `order_number` char(9) NOT NULL,   `order_origin` char(7)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `customer_order_reference` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
> `status` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,   `is_completed_with_cancellations`
> tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,   `payment_type` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
> `shipment_type` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,   `requested_ship_date` datetime
> DEFAULT NULL,   `apply_taxes` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
> `totals_tax_incl` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,   `total_cost` decimal(8,2)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `total_cost_ex_ship` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
> `gross_profit` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `gross_profit_ex_ship`
> decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `gross_margin_percent` decimal(3,2)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `gross_margin_percent_ex_ship` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT
> NULL,   `average_markup_percent` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
> `average_markup_percent_ex_ship` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
> `subtotal` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `subtotal_ex_shipping`
> decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `subtotal_applicable_to_taxes`
> decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `grand_total` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
> `grand_total_ex_ship` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `internal_notes`
> varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,   `external_notes` varchar(4000) DEFAULT
> NULL,   `completed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `created_date`
> datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
> `customer_id` varchar(28) DEFAULT NULL,   `customer_add_id`
> varchar(28) DEFAULT NULL,   `total_discount` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT
> NULL,   `recipient_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
> `accounting_invoice_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `warehouse_code`
> varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> ### --
> -- Dumping data for table `tv_sales_orders`
>
> INSERT INTO `tv_sales_orders` (`sales_order_id`, `order_number`,
> `order_origin`, `customer_order_reference`, `status`,
> `is_completed_with_cancellations`, `payment_type`, `shipment_type`,
> `requested_ship_date`, `apply_taxes`, `totals_tax_incl`, `total_cost`,
> `total_cost_ex_ship`, `gross_profit`, `gross_profit_ex_ship`,
> `gross_margin_percent`, `gross_margin_percent_ex_ship`,
> `average_markup_percent`, `average_markup_percent_ex_ship`,
> `subtotal`, `subtotal_ex_shipping`, `subtotal_applicable_to_taxes`,
> `grand_total`, `grand_total_ex_ship`, `internal_notes`,
> `external_notes`, `completed_date`, `created_date`, `modified_date`,
> `customer_id`, `customer_add_id`, `total_discount`, `recipient_name`,
> `accounting_invoice_id`, `warehouse_code`) VALUES ('1', 'so1', NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, '2021-08-28 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL), ('2', 'so2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2021-08-28 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('3', 'so3', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2021-08-28
> 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('4',
> 'so4', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, '2021-08-28 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL), ('5', 'so5', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2021-08-28 00:00:00', NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
>
> ---
>
> ### --
> -- Table structure for table `tv_sales_orders_lines`
>
> CREATE TABLE `tv_sales_orders_lines` (   `sales_order_id` varchar(28)
> NOT NULL,   `product_tv_id` varchar(28) NOT NULL,   `quantity`
> decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `cost_price` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
> `sell_price_ex_tax` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `line_notes`
> varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,   `sell_price_incl_tax` decimal(6,2)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `line_total` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
> `line_number` int(3) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
> CHARSET=latin1;
>
> ### --
> -- Dumping data for table `tv_sales_orders_lines`
>
> INSERT INTO `tv_sales_orders_lines` (`sales_order_id`,
> `product_tv_id`, `quantity`, `cost_price`, `sell_price_ex_tax`,
> `line_notes`, `sell_price_incl_tax`, `line_total`, `line_number`)
> VALUES ('1', '1', '4.00', '1.00', '1.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
> ('1', '3', '5.00', '2.00', '1.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('2', '1',
> '5.00', '2.00', '1.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('2', '2', '1.00',
> '2.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('3', '2', '5.00', '1.00',
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
>
> ---
>
> ### --
> -- Table structure for table `tv_sales_orders_packing_lists`
>
> CREATE TABLE `tv_sales_orders_packing_lists` (   `packing_list_id`
> varchar(28) NOT NULL,   `sales_order_id` varchar(28) DEFAULT NULL,
> `pack_list_number` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,   `status` int(5) DEFAULT
> NULL,   `requested_shipping_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
> `shipped_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `courier` varchar(45) DEFAULT
> NULL,   `tracking_reference` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
> `tracking_reference_2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,   `delivery_notes`
> varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,   `printed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
> `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `warehouse_id` varchar(28)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `courier_company_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL )
> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> ---
>
> ### --
> -- Table structure for table `tv_sales_orders_packing_list_lines`
>
> CREATE TABLE `tv_sales_orders_packing_list_lines` (
> `packing_list_id` varchar(28) NOT NULL,   `product_id` varchar(28) NOT
> NULL,   `line_number` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,   `quantity_requested`
> decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,   `quantity_packed` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT
> NULL,   `quantity_back_order` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
> `cost_price_fifo` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
> CHARSET=latin1;
>
> ---
>
> ### --
> -- Table structure for table `tv_suppliers`
>
> CREATE TABLE `tv_suppliers` (   `supplier_id` varchar(28) NOT NULL,
> `supplier_code` varchar(28) DEFAULT NULL,   `supplier_name`
> varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   `supplier_phone` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
> `supplier_fax` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,   `supplier_currency` varchar(4)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `supplier_delivery_terms` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
> `supplier_shipping_terms` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
> `supplier_payment_terms` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
> `local_update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
> CHARSET=latin1;
>
> ### --
> -- Dumping data for table `tv_suppliers`
>
> INSERT INTO `tv_suppliers` (`supplier_id`, `supplier_code`,
> `supplier_name`, `supplier_phone`, `supplier_fax`,
> `supplier_currency`, `supplier_delivery_terms`,
> `supplier_shipping_terms`, `supplier_payment_terms`,
> `local_update_date`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'supplier 1', NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
>
> ### --
> -- Indexes for dumped tables
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `tv_product`
> -- ALTER TABLE `tv_product`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tv_id`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `tv_product_supplier`
> -- ALTER TABLE `tv_product_supplier`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tv_id`,`supplier_id`,`product_supplier_id`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `tv_sales_orders`
> -- ALTER TABLE `tv_sales_orders`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sales_order_id`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `tv_sales_orders_lines`
> -- ALTER TABLE `tv_sales_orders_lines`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sales_order_id`,`product_tv_id`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `tv_sales_orders_packing_lists`
> -- ALTER TABLE `tv_sales_orders_packing_lists`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`packing_list_id`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `tv_sales_orders_packing_list_lines`
> -- ALTER TABLE `tv_sales_orders_packing_list_lines`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`packing_list_id`);
>
> --
> -- Indexes for table `tv_suppliers`
> -- ALTER TABLE `tv_suppliers`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`supplier_id`);

Comment: You've asked two separate questions in one post, which isn't appropriate. This is a question and answer site, not a *numbered list of questions* site. It would also be extremely helpful if you provided sample data for each table and the output you'd like to obtain from that data.

Comment: Updated - Thanks

Comment: Please note: "sample data" is NOT an "image of data" instead: a simple text table which we can use as inserts, or set of inserts is preferred. Also, sample data implies "for each table" so 5 tables requires 5 samples. The intent is to give us a way to demonstrate how to solve your problem.

Comment: updated again, ill check your answer thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that "***All the products listed under supplier***" requires that you design the query using `from products` because products may exist that have not been sold, and certainly may have been sold outside the date range. Additionally to allow these conditions where products may exist without matching sales order data you need to use OUTER joins so here I have used `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to both order related tables. To limit the quantities etc to just the date range this is handled in a subquery. Output of zero instead of NULL is achieved by using COALESCE

```
SELECT
       p.code AS "Code"
     , p.name AS "Name"
     , COALESCE(SUM(s.quantity),0) AS "Qty"
     , COALESCE(SUM(s.cost_price * sol.quantity),0) AS "Cost Total Excl"
     , COALESCE(SUM(s.line_total),0) AS "Sale Total incl"
FROM tv_product AS p
INNER JOIN tv_product_supplier AS ps ON p.tv_id = ps.tv_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
           sol.product_tv_id
         , sol.quantity
         , sol.cost_price
         , sol.quantity
         , sol.line_total
    FROM tv_sales_orders_lines AS sol ON sol.product_tv_id = p.tv_id
    INNER JOIN tv_sales_orders AS so ON so.sales_order_id = sol.sales_order_id
    WHERE so.completed_date BETWEEN '2021-08-20' AND '2021-08-26'
    ) AS s ON s.product_tv_id = p.tv_id
WHERE ps.supplier_id = "3608989204038919213"
AND p.is_archived = 0  /* assume this means not archived */
AND NOT p.code = "SHIP"
GROUP BY p.code,
         p.name
```

The second question does appear to need limiting the results only to sold products so for this we should use inner joins.

```
SELECT
  p.code AS "Code",
  p.name AS "Name",
  SUM(sol.quantity) AS "Qty",
  SUM(sol.cost_price * sol.quantity) AS "Cost Total Excl",
  SUM(sol.line_total) AS "Sale Total incl"
FROM tv_sales_orders AS so
INNER JOIN tv_sales_orders_lines AS sol ON so.sales_order_id = sol.sales_order_id
INNER JOIN tv_product AS p ON sol.product_tv_id = p.tv_id
INNER JOIN tv_product_supplier AS ps ON p.tv_id = ps.tv_id
WHERE so.completed_date BETWEEN '2021-08-20' AND '2021-08-26'
AND so.status <> '12004' /* assume this is a string */
GROUP BY p.code,
         p.name
```

Please take care when using `between` if the `so.completed_date` column is accurate to a time unit smaller then a day you can get the wrong results by missing some rows. You can use this more reliable approach instead:

```
WHERE so.completed_date >= '2021-08-20' AND so.completed_date < '2021-08-27'
```

Noting that the more recent date has shifted up one day to the 27th. so any orders completed **during** the final day will also be included.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that is working now, all data showing on the one line, however the QTY and total and Cost seems to be not limited to the date range, possibly sold over all time, not just the date between x and Y? Also do you know how to make the figures 0 if there has been no sales rather than null?

Comment: sorry I mean - Thanks Paul, the top one works, but the total and the QTy and cost is not limited to the between Y and X if I use the second one it does not include all the other items from the supplier not sold between X & Y?

Comment: I have amended the first query based on your note above, you only need one query for that, no union is necessary, it includes all products for the supplier regardless of the date range. That is why I use `from products` and then a `left outer join` - to get all products from the supplier. The second query is to meet this `Total products sold, QTY and total price which were on orders not cancelled between date x and y listed by line item.`

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I keep getting an error on your first SQL code... [quote] #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON sol.product_tv_id = p.tv_id
    WHERE so.completed_date BETWEEN '2021-08-20'' at line 18[/quote]

Any Idea why?

Comment: `'2021-08-20''`   the date literal should have a single quote on each side, is that single quote character repeated accidentally in your code? What is the content of just row 18?